# JQuery: How do I passively watch an element to see when a class is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using Slick Slider (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I want to hide the Previous button and show it only when the slider advances/scrolls.

The only way I can think of doing this is to have the Previous Button `.fadeIn()` when the `.slick-active` class is removed from the first slide element. However, I am unsure how to trigger this event.

I can't use a `.click()` function as Slick enables you to drag on mobile devices.

Is there a way I can passively "watch" an element to see if it has a class added/removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prosy Arceno's answer is correct, however I discovered Slick Slider already covers cases like mine with events.

So All I need to to do was:

```
  // On after slide change
  $('.js-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $(".prevBtn").fadeIn();
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

This is an example:

```js
var targetNode = document.querySelector('.red');
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  }
};

setInterval(function() {
  targetNode.classList.toggle("red");
}, 1000);

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="red">red</p>
```